# Dialogflow ES fulfillment did not reply

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

[Update] with the entire code

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
db.settings(settings);
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  // console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 
  function writeToDb (agent) {
    const startDate = agent.parameters.startdate;
    // Always assume user enter time in the past (for existing time)
    console.log("start date:" + startDate);
    if (Date.parse(startDate) > Date.now()) {
        startDate.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear() - 1);
        // console.log("modify start date to: " + startDate);
    }
    const dfRef = db.collection('period').doc(request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.sender.id);
    agent.add('Got it. That me write it done for ya');
    dfRef.get().then(user => {
        if(!user.exists) {
            dfRef.create({dates: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(startDate)})
              .then(() => {
              }).catch(err => {
                console.log('error create firestore date entry:' + `${err}`);
            });
        } else {
            dfRef.update({dates: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(startDate)})
              .then(() => {
              }).catch(err => {
                console.log('error update firestore date entry:' + `${err}`);
            });
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error access firestore date:' + `${err}`);
    });
  }
  
  function readFromDb (agent) {
    // Get the database collection 'dialogflow' and document 'agent'
    const startDate = agent.parameters.startdate;
    const future = agent.parameters.future;
    const dialogflowAgentDoc = db.collection('period').doc(request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.sender.id);

    // Get the value of 'entry' in the document and send it to the user
    return dialogflowAgentDoc.get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          var darray = doc.data().dates;
          if (darray.length > 0) {
            if (future) {
              agent.add('let me calculate for you..');
               var next = new Date(darray[darray.length-2]);
               const dayDiff = calculateSchedule(darray);
               next.setDate(next.getDate() + dayDiff * 1);
               agent.add(next.toLocaleDateString('en-us', {month:"short", day: 'numeric', weekday: 'short'}));
            } else {
              agent.add('let me look up for you..');
              agent.add(new Date(darray[darray.length-1]).toLocaleDateString('en-us', {month:"short", day: 'numeric', weekday: 'short'}));
            }
           
          } else {
            agent.add('I cant find anything :( ');
          }
          
        } else {
            agent.add('something was wrong, I cant find your record :/');
        }
        return Promise.resolve('complete!');
      }).catch(err => {
        agent.add(`Error reading entry from the Firestore database. ${err}`);
      });
  }

  function calculateSchedule(arr) {
    // emitted..
  }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('it start today', writeToDb);
  intentMap.set('when did it start', readFromDb);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

[Original]
Hi my dialogflow ES is connected to fb messenger and the purpose is to reply a message after I recorded what the customer say into DB, I checked if the document exist: here is my code

```
  function writeToDb (agent) {
    const startDate = agent.parameters.startdate;
    const dfRef = db.collection('start').doc('my_id');
    dfRef.get().then(user => {
        if(!user.exists) {
            dfRef.create({dates: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(startDate)})
              .then(() => {
                agent.add('Got it. let me write it down for ya');
              }).catch(err => {
                console.log(`${err}`);
            });
        } else {
            dfRef.update({dates: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(startDate)})
              .then(() => {
                agent.add('Got it. let me write it down for ya');
              }).catch(err => {
                console.log(`${err}`);
            });
        }
    });
  }
```

the startDate value is successfully store in the firestore. However, I never get the reply message, is there anything I did wrong? I felt it should be simple enough.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to set up the [`IntentMap()` see step 5 and 6](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/fulfillment#:%7E:text=definitions%2C%20there%20are-,intentMap.set(),-calls.%20These%20calls).

In the intentMap, you will need to add a map from the Intent name to a function that will do the handling when that Intent triggers the webhook. You can have a different handler function for each Intent, use the same function for some, have those functions call other functions, whatever you need. Finally use `agent.handleRequest(intentMap);`.

Comment: I did. Its more like an issue with race condition.

Comment: @Audrey can you post the entire code so I can change my answer and see what is happening?

Comment: didn't see the comment until now. Thanks. I uploaded the entire code except helper functions